# Panda's data frame filtering on rows that are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

With Jupyter Notebook and Panda's I'm trying to filter 'NaN' values from a column in a dataframe.
I have uses the code you can see below.
`empty_art = df.loc[df['Artikelnr.'] == 'NaN']`

This does work when I am filtering for other values that are not empty.
For example `leeg_art = df.loc[df['Artikelnr.'] == 'X99999']` works perfect.
I have tried the `isnull()` function as well but it doesn't seem to be working either.
I must be making some mistake in the syntax, I just started with programming and Pandas so it's probably something silly.

I expected to see a data frame with the empty columns of artikelnr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Artikelnr.'].isnull()]
```